# How to skip the SSIS package failure even if the task fails

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-2012

An ssis package as shown below;It  has to be designed in such a way that if the email tasks fails, the package should not fail.

The 2nd precedence constraints is used as **completed**,so it would skip the start email,in case it fails and package would not fail

The question is how to implement it on the last task,End email.In case this task fail then it should not fail the whole package

[image]

Comment: You could put `three` and `End Email` into a sequence container and connect the Completion constraint to that. Not clear what you are wanting to achieve and why you would ignore errors on those tasks, there are other options that could be used.

Answer (score 2):

Use a dummy task, that you connect the `End Email` task with a `completion` constraint. An empty `Sequence Container` that you could name "dummy container" or "Endpoint" should do the work.

Answer (score 2):

Just go to `End Email` properties and change the following properties:

- **ForceExecutionValue** *--> True*
- **ForceExecutionResult** *--> Success*
- **FailPackageOnFailure** *--> False*
- **FailParentOnFailure** *--> False*

[image]

Comment: I can only advise against the use of force execution settings. There are rare use cases when this is an appropriate approach. The main reason is, you will never know if the task failed. The integration services part of sql-server is logging every step of an execution, so even if you would not wan't the complete package to fail, you want the log to be correct. As an example: A kid fails an exam at math but he doesn't fail his current grade. Yet that doesn't mean he actually passed the math exam. Another issue, is that this property is hidden at first. You also might want to handle errors later.